# Can't set up AFNetworking (2.0) JSON request

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to get AFNetworking 2.0 working here, but I'm running against quite a lot of errors.

My progress:

1. Implemented the "AFNetworking" folder as groups in my xCode project.
2. In my headerfile i've implemented the AFNetworking.h file
3. This is my code in the m file:

   ```
   -(void)afNetworking {
       AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
       manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
       [manager GET:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Kortrijk,be"      parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
           // ResponseObject is json parsed in een dictionary
           NSLog(@"Country: %@, City: %@, Coordinates: (longitude: %@, latitude: %@)",
                 [[responseObject valueForKey:@"sys"] valueForKey:@"country"],
                 [responseObject valueForKey:@"name"],
                 [[responseObject valueForKey:@"coord"] valueForKey:@"lon"],
                 [[responseObject valueForKey:@"coord"] valueForKey:@"lat"]
                 );
       } failure:nil];

   }
   ```

It doesn't get to my code, but I get 15 Match-O-Linker errors. Any idea how this is possible?
These are the match o linker errors:

[image: http://d.pr/i/6a6j]

Note: I've started coding this app in IOS6 and Xcode4. Now on Xcode 5 and IOS7. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: You can try to set Build Active Architecture Only to NO from Build Settings of AFNetworking target.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you haven't linked to the frameworks that AFNetworking requires. There are two approaches that can fix that:

1. If using Xcode 5, you can turn on Modules in your target's "Build Settings" and it will automatically attach the necessary libraries for you, eliminating these linker warnings.

   [image: Modules]
2. If you're not using Modules (either don't want to for some reason or using old version of Xcode), you can manually add the appropriate frameworks (Security.framework and SystemConfiguration.framework) via "Link Binary With Libraries" section of the "Build Phases" settings for your target:

   [image: add libraries]